# what is the notation of a triangle side?

Tags: geometry, notation, euclidean-geometry

For instance, in triangle ABC, how to notate the side AB? Since, as far as I know, to notate the length of the side $AB$, we simply write $AB$ and I presume that we cannot notate the side AB as $AB$ since it is different to the length of the side AB. I also presume that we use the symbol $\overline {AB}$ since the side AB in triangle ABC is a line segment.

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Many textbooks agree with you but I personally do not. In writing $AB+BC=100$ it is pretty clear that we mean that the sum of the lengths of the $AB$ and $BC$-sides is $100$, so I find the notation $\overline{AB}$ pretty redundant. $AB$ or $c$ is just fine.

Comment: @wawar05 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

$AB,BC,AC$ are nice notations, often the following notation is used

- $a$ for side $BC$
- $b$ for side $AC$
- $c$ for side $AB$

and

- $\alpha$ angle in $A$
- $\beta$ angle in $B$
- $\gamma$ angle in $C$

[image]